# base64_encode acts strange

Tags: php, base64

I'm trying to base64_encode and decode an XML request:

```
$xml = '<root>
    <term id="KEY">VAL</term>
    <term id="KEY2">VAL2</term>
    <term id="KEY3">VAL3</term>
</root>';
echo base64_encode( $xml );
echo base64_decode( $xml );
```

Why does this return this strange stuff on decode?

```
®Š-µêæ‰Ò„aPþ×«š×«š'J•½¿µêæµêæ‰Ò„cu@/íz¹¿®Š-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should decode something that is already encoded, and `$xml` is not.

Comment: Yeah, thanx m8. Noticed that myself after posting. Must be working too late :D

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to decode the original string of XML, not the base64 encoded string.

```
$xml = '<root>
    <term id="KEY">VAL</term>
    <term id="KEY2">VAL2</term>
    <term id="KEY3">VAL3</term>
</root>';

$encoded_xml = base64_encode( $xml );

echo $encoded_xml;
echo base64_decode( $encoded_xml );
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to decode the original XML string, without having saved the encoded version.

Try

```
$xml = '...';
$encoded = base64_encode($xml);
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are trying to encode the XML and not the actual encoded string.